# how to order the data being written to a text file by score in c#

Tags: c#, text-files

i am making a quiz application for my computing coursework and i am working on the end screen and in the end screen i have method called savescore()

the savescore() is meant to save the users' username,score and time into a text file. the savescore() method saves the users details into a text-file called scores perfectly but my problem is that when i write the user details into the text file i want the data to be written into the scores text file in order of descending score and i cant figure out how to do that.

```
 private void SaveScore()
    {
        string file = @"..\..\textfiles\scores.txt";

        try
        {
            //
            // Create file if not exists
            //
            if (!File.Exists(file))
            {
                File.Create(file).Dispose();
            }

            //
            // Create DataTable
            //
            DataColumn nameColumn = new DataColumn("name", typeof(String));
            DataColumn scoreColumn = new DataColumn("score", typeof(int));
            DataColumn timeColumn = new DataColumn("time", typeof(long));



            DataTable scores = new DataTable();
            scores.Columns.Add(nameColumn);
            scores.Columns.Add(scoreColumn);
            scores.Columns.Add(timeColumn);


            //
            // Read CSV and populate DataTable
            //
            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(file))
            {
                streamReader.ReadLine();

                while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    String[] row = streamReader.ReadLine().Split(',');
                    scores.Rows.Add(row);
                }
            }

            Boolean scoreFound = false;

            //
            // If user exists and new score is higher, update 
            //
            foreach (DataRow score in scores.Rows)
            {
                if ((String)score["name"] == player.Name)
                {
                    if ((int)score["score"] < player.Score)
                    {
                        score["score"] = player.Score;
                        score["time"] = elapsedtime;

                    }

                    scoreFound = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            //
            // If user doesn't exist then add user/score
            //
            if (!scoreFound)
            {
                scores.Rows.Add(player.Name, player.Score, elapsedtime);
            }

            //
            // Write changes to CSV (empty then rewrite)
            //
            File.WriteAllText(file, string.Empty);

            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            stringBuilder.AppendLine("name,score,time");

            foreach (DataRow score in scores.Rows)
            {
                stringBuilder.AppendLine(score["name"] + "," + score["score"] + "," + score["time"]);
            }

            File.WriteAllText(file, stringBuilder.ToString());
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error saving high score:\n\n" + ex.ToString(), "Error");
        }

    }
```

so i someone could edit my current code to save the user details in descending order in terms of the score that would be fantastic and thanks in advance.

Comment: A DataTable can be Sorted and Filtered without all that code.  I would think a `List<T>` would be better suited than a DataTable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [DataTable.Select method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.select?view=netframework-4.7.2) to achieve that. With the select method you can filter and sort the row in a table. 
Here is the changed `foreach` statement that uses the method to sort the data.

```
foreach (DataRow score in scores.Select(null, "score DESC"))
{
   stringBuilder.AppendLine(score["name"] + "," + score["score"] + "," + score["time"]);
}
```